# Re-Compiling and Re-running a Java code while it is running

Tags: java, compiler-construction

In an Unix environment, if I am running a Java code and I would like to re-run it with different parameters, could I recompile it with no data loss? Will the previous Java task still run without get stuck?

Cheers,
Simone

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. I'm unsure what you mean. Could you perhaps show some code?

Comment: In most environments, if you recompile Java .class files while the app is running, the running app will not be affected -- it will continue to run with the old code.  However, if the app has not already loaded everything, .class files that have not yet been referenced by the app may be picked up unexpectedly, leading to "unusual" behavior.

Comment: Well there's [HCR](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) and similar things

Comment: @Aidanc I didn't set command line parameters thus I wanted to change some Java code and re-compile it, but I am still running another instance of that code. I would like to keep it running while I start the new Java instance.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you. It has been running for 2 days now, I think I loaded all things it needed. I'll re-compile and run it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run multilpe instances of the same java program with different (command line ) parameters without re-compiling.

Running different versions of the same program and re-compiling at run time is possible, but if you modify a class file while the program is running it may affect the current runtime if that file had not been loaded yet.
You should create another working copy of the class files or jar files and then launch the copy after modifying it if you want to gave two different versions running at the same time.
If your program modifications can be changed to property file or other configuration file mods, I think that is a better solution.